# How to configure postfix to connect to port 26 on the remote host?

Tags: server, postfix

My ISP blocks outgoing connections to port 25 (well, with one exception for their SMTP server).

The remote host for one particular email address is also configured to listen on port 26. Is there any way of configuring Postfix to connect to port *26* on the remote host?

Comment: Shame no one ever posted something explaining on how to actually do it.

Comment: @BrunoPereira: I did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can handle this with a [transport map](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps). First tell postfix to use a map, with the following in `main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Then in `/etc/postfix/transport` add the custom route:

```
example.net smtp:example.net:26
```

Then build the map database:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

Answer (score 4):

As a temporary measure you can try to redirect all traffic going out of your computer from port 25 to port 26 with `iptables` just for testing:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --src 0/0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 26
```

Comment: Great, I'll try that.

Comment: :D I love it when a plan comes together!